# Can i access a Javascript array in my asp.net code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have a javascript array and want to access it when the page is posted on the server. Is this possible? I should be able to access the array using asp.net code. Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use HiddenField(runat=server) and store it there with comma separated value. and then access your hidden field in code behind.

to store in hidden field:

```
document.yourformname.Hidden1.value = test.join();

<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Code Behind:

```
test = document.yourformname.Hidden1.value.split(",");
```

Comment: You can try saving it in `JSON` and use Json.net (or other libs) to deserialize it.

Answer (score 1):

to store in hidden field:

```
 document.getElementById("gGlobalArrayHidden").value = gGlobalArray.join(',');

<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

---

Code Behind:

```
string[] arr = gGlobalArrayHidden.Value.Split(",".ToCharArray());
```